# Pop and push in stacks

Tags: c++

I have a Data Structures assignment to use stacks for postfix algorithm. I think I'm nearly there but am struggling on a couple of things.

1. What do I put into the postfixstack.pop() arguments on Line 83 of cpp file?
2. How do I check if the stack is empty on Line 87 of cpp file?

I have 2 files, a .cpp and a .h file, both of them are below.

Thanks for any help.

```
            using namespace std;
            #include <iostream>
            #include <stdlib.h>
            #include <string>
            #include "stack.h"

  //Purpose of the program: **
    //Algorithm: **
    int main()
    {
      stack postfixstack;  // integer stack
      string expression;   // user entered expression

      cout << "type a postfix expression: " ;
      cin >> expression;

      int i = 0;  // character position within expression
      char item;  // one char out of the expression

      int box1;  // receive things from pop
      int box2;  // receive things from pop

      while (expression[i] != '\0')
        {
         try
           {
         item = expression[i];  // current char

         // ** do all the steps in the algorithm given in Notes-1

         if (item >= '0' && item <= '9') {
             postfixstack.push(item);
             }
         else if (item == '+' || item == '-' || item == '*') {
             if (item == '+') {
                 postfixstack.pop(box1);
                 postfixstack.pop(box2);
                 int tempResult = (box1 + box2);
                 postfixstack.push(tempResult);
             }
             if (item == '-') {
                 postfixstack.pop(box1);
                 postfixstack.pop(box2);
                 int tempResult = (box1 - box2);
                 postfixstack.push(tempResult);
             }
             if (item == '*') {
                 postfixstack.pop(box1);
                 postfixstack.pop(box2);
                 int tempResult = (box1 * box2);
                 postfixstack.push(tempResult);
             }
         }
         else {
             throw ;

         }


           } // this closes try
          // Catch exceptions and report problems and quit the program now (exit(1)). 
          // Error messages describe what is wrong with the expression.
          catch (stack::Overflow) {
            {cerr << "Error: You have caused the stack to overflow." << endl; }
            exit(1);
          }
          catch (stack::Underflow)
            {cerr << "Error: You have caused the stack to underflow." << endl;
            exit(1);
          }
          catch (char const* errormsg ) // for invalid item case
            {cerr << "Error: You have entered an invalid item." << endl;
            exit(1);
          }

          i++; // go back to the loop after incrementing i

        }// end of while

     // After the loop successfully completes: 
     // Pop the result and show it.

      *postfixstack.pop();*

     // If anything is left on the stack, an incomplete expression 
     // was found so inform the user.
      if (*Need to check if stack is empty*) {
          cerr << "Elements remain on the stack, incomplete expression error" << endl;
          exit(1);
      }

    }// end of the program
```

****This is the beginning of the header file*****

```
    // File type: header file stack.h
    //=======================================================

    //----- Globally setting up the aliases ----------------

    const int MAX = 10;   // The MAX number of elements for the stack
                          // MAX is unknown to the client

    typedef int el_t;      // the el_t type is char for now
                          // el_t is unknown to the client
    //-------------------------------------------------------


    class stack
    { 

     private: // to be hidden from the client

       el_t     el[MAX];       // el is  an array of el_t's
       int      top;           // top is index to the top of stack

     public:  // available to the client

      // Add exception handling classes here  
         class Overflow {};  // empty class – used as an exception name only
         class Underflow {};     // empty class – used as an exception name only


      // prototypes to be used by the client
      // Note that no parameter variables are given

      stack();   // constructor to create an object
      ~stack();  // destructor  to destroy an object

      // PURPOSE: if not full, enters an element at the top;
      //          otherwise throws an exception - Overflow
      // PARAMETER: pass the element to be pushed
      void push(el_t);

      // PURPOSE: if not empty, removes and gives back the top element;
      //          otherwise throws an exception - Underflow
      // PARAMETER: provide variable to receive the popped element (by ref)
      void pop(el_t&);

      // PURPOSE: if not empty, gives the top element without removing it;
      //          otherwise, throws an exception - Underflow
      // PARAMETER: provide the top element of the stack (pass by reference)
      void topElem(el_t&);

       //PURPOSE: Determines if the stack is Empty. Returns true if stack is empty
      bool isEmpty();

      //PURPOSE: Determines if the stack is Full. Returns true if stack is full
      bool isFull();

      //PURPOSE: Displays all of the elements of the stack
      void displayAll();

      //PURPOSE: Clears all of the elements in the stack until it is empty
      void clearIt();

    };
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are implementing the stack as an array you can use the index (your top variable) to keep track of your stack's size as long as its use is well defined.

For instance, you can say that top is pointing to the next available place to put a new element so that an empty stack would have top == 0. This would solve the part for checking if an array is empty.

Following that same definition when you pop the stack you're removing the top element. If the datatype your stack is holding is a simple type you can just decrease the value of top by one.

```
void pop (el_t& val) //Perhaps return the value instead of return by reference
{
    val= el[--top]; //Decrease top first because top is pointing to next EMPTY space.
}
```